# The ftp client in Matlab does not work correctly on a non standard port

Tags: matlab, ftp, vsftpd

Vsftpd is installed on the server.
If the configuration file doesn't have the listen_port value, I can connect via Matlab, view folders, and upload some files.

```
vsftpd.conf: #listen_port=6666
```

matlab:

```
>> ftpobj = ftp('ip_adress','matlab','matlab')
ftpobj =
  FTP Object
     host: ip_adress
     user: matlab
      dir: /
     mode: binary
>> dir(ftpobj)
1.version        azaz             folder           version.version
```

If I change the port(let's say 6666), Matlab connects to ftp, but can't get a list of directories or download files from it.

```
vsftpd.conf: listen_port=6666
```

matlab:

```
>> ftpobj = ftp('ip_adress:6666','matlab','matlab')
ftpobj = 
  FTP Object
     host: ip_adress
     user: matlab
      dir: /
     mode: binary
>> dir(ftpobj)
Error using ftp/dir (line 66)
Java exception occurred:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:271)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:502)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listNames(FTPClient.java:1950) 
>>
```

Server: orange Pi 3
vsftpd version-latest stable(21.04.2020)

Client: win10 pro
Matlab 2020a